# Get stored id's using iteration

Tags: php

I please need some help:
I have this database, which has this fields with their respect values:

```
agency_id | hostess_id
3         | 12-4-6
5         | 19-4-7
1         | 1
```

In hostess_id are stored all hostesses ids that are associated with that agency_id but separated with a "-"

Well, i login as a hostess, and i have the id=4
I need to retrieve all the agency_id which contain the id=4 , i can't do this with like operator.. i tried to do it by saving the hostess_id row to an array, then implode it, but i can't resolve it like this.

Please, please any idea?

Comment: No offense, but four questions within one hour? It kinda feels like you want StackOverflow to write your application for you.

Comment: No offense taken, but the same 4 questions are for the same thing, and well, i can't help that i am very disoriented, if it looks like an offense to you, all my postings,just set a down vote, or even close it, moral, it's not what i am up to now!
Thanks!

Comment: You'd be better redesigning your table to store each agency/hostess record as a separate database record: if you were using a comma separator rather than -, then you could use FIND_IN_SET()... as it is, you need to use LIKE in your SQL query instead

Answer (score 1):

You should change your database design. What you are describing is a typical N:N relation

Agencies:

```
agency_id | name
3         | Miami
5         | Annapolis
1         | New York
```

Hosteses

```
Hostes_id | name
4         | Helen
12        | May
19        | June
```

AgencyHostes

```
Hostes_id | agency_id
4         | 1
4         | 3
4         | 5
12        | 1
12        | 3
19        | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that I absolutely agree with @JvdBerg on that this is terrible database design that needs to be normalized.

Let's think for a minute though, that you have no way of changing the database layout and that you must solve this with SQL, an inefficient but working solution would be

```
select agency_id from tablename where
  hostess_id LIKE '4-%' OR
  hostess_id LIKE '%-4-%' OR
  hostess_id LIKE '%-4'
```

if you were searching for all agencies with hostess id 4. I build this on sqlfiddle to illustrate more thoroughly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09a52/1

Mind though, that this SQL statement is hard to optimize since an index structure for substring matching is rarely employed. For very short id lists it will work okay though. If you have ANY chance at changing the table structure, normalize your schema like @JvdBerg suggested and look up database design and normal forms on google.

Comment: Quick SQL Fiddle tip: you can copy/paste OP's data into the "Text to DDL" feature and quickly generate the necessary DDL/DML to work against; makes it easier than typing it up manually.  For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c787

Comment: Sweet, never noticed that. Thank you!